# Why does tcpdump not recognise piped input?

Tags: command-line

1. I obtained a packet capture file:

   ```
   $ sudo tcpdump -w file.pcap
   ```
2. I can then analyse that file:

   ```
   $ tcpdump -r file.pcap
   ```

   I can even use file redirection to read from standard input:

   ```
   $ tcpdump -r - < file.pcap
   ```
3. However, I cannot use a pipe to read from standard input:

   ```
   $ cat file.pcap | tcpdump -r -
   tcpdump: unknown file format
   ```

   This *should* work.  What's going on?

OS X Yosemite 10.10
tcpdump version 4.3.0 -- Apple version 59
libpcap version 1.5.3 - Apple version 47

---

<sup>I'm actually trying to `sudo tcpdump -w - | tee file.pcap | tcpdump -r -`, which gives rise to the same problem—however it appears to arise with any form of piped input.</sup>

Comment: I just ran into this myself. I'm glad your Q is here so I know I'm not crazy ... no solution yet. The same commands work fine on Ubuntu

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is still an issue with [OS X Mojave 10.14.2](https://opensource.apple.com/release/macos-1014.html) (libpcap 1.0.1 Apple 79.200.4, tcpdump 4.9.2 Apple 83.200.2). It's ultimately a bug in Apple's patches to libpcap and tcpdump.

In addition to using upstream `tcpdump` (which is available in Homebrew), you could also:

- Use `tshark` (part of Wireshark), which works similarly to `tcpdump`.
- Write the packets to a temporary file.
- Prefix the stream with 4 null bytes:

  `sudo tcpdump -i en0 -w - | cat <(printf "\0\0\0\0") - | tcpdump -nvr -`

### Cause (and why inserting nulls works)

Apple [has patched their tcpdump](https://opensource.apple.com/source/tcpdump/tcpdump-83.200.2/tcpdump/tcpdump.c.auto.html) such that it tries to read files as PCAP-NG format first:

```c
#else /* __APPLE__ */
        pd = pcap_ng_open_offline(RFileName, ebuf);
```

They also added a `-P` option to emit packets in `pcapng` format.

`pcap_ng_open_offline` ends up in `pcap_fopen_offline_internal(..., isng=1)`.  This flow calls `pcap_ng_check_header` early (see [`if (isng)` in `pcap_fopen_offline_internal`](https://opensource.apple.com/source/libpcap/libpcap-67/libpcap/savefile.c.auto.html)), and on failure, jumps into the `bad:` label.

That `bad:` label attempts to `fseeko` to seek the file back to the start:

```c
 bad:
    fseeko(fp, offset, SEEK_SET);
    if (p != NULL)
        free(p);
    return (NULL);
```

But you can't seek a FIFO, so we're still reading from the same spot!  `fseeko` would return an error, *but this error is ignored*.

On `pcap_ng_open_offline` returning an error, Apple's patch then calls `pcap_open_offline`, which follows a similar control flow to normal pcap. However, because the file pointer on the FIFO is still forward by 4 bytes, the next set of headers have the fifo's magics, and so `tcpdump` gives up.

You can work around this by inserting 4 extra `NULL` bytes at the start of your pipe, with a little shell-script trickery:

```sh
tcpdump -i en0 -w - | cat <(printf "\0\0\0\0") - | tcpdump -nvr -
```

This means that when `fseeko` fails, you'll be in the correct spot in the FIFO for the "actual" magic.

However, there are still some limitations:

- `tcpdump -P` (Apple-specific `pcapng` flag) still doesn't work.
- These files are no longer valid `pcap` files. If you wanted to read it with another tool (or even a non-Apple `tcpdump`), you'll need to `tee` the output *before* `cat`.

This also works with `tshark` (which can output `pcapng`, and doesn't work as a source without this work-around):

```sh
tshark -F pcapng -w - | cat <(printf "\0\0\0\0") - | tcpdump -nvr -
```

**However, I wouldn't suggest putting this work-around in anything long term.** 
It will break once Apple fixes this bug, or if your users have a non-Apple `tcpdump` on OSX (such as with Homebrew).

Comment: Detailed and comprehensive.  Amazing.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem on Mavericks (10.9.5).  It's probably not the best answer but I downloaded the open source version of tcpdump (tcpdump-4.6.2) and put it in my path before the system version and it works with pipes.  Of course, you lose the extra Apple-specific functionality.